# Call copy constructor instead of move constructor?

Tags: c++

I define a class `A` like this:

```
class A {
public:
    A(){
        cout << "A constructing..." << endl;
    }
    A(const A &a){
        cout << "A copy constructing..." << endl;
    }
    A(A&& a){
        strcpy(name, a.name);
        cout << "A move constructing..." << endl;
    }
    ~A(){
        cout << "A destructing..." << name << endl;
    }
};
```

And a simple function:

```
A f(A&& b) {
    cout << "------after call------" << endl;
    A f = b; // Use "A f(b)" to get the same effect
    cout << "------before return------" << endl;
    return f;
}
```

And when I call `auto test = f(move(b));`, why would it call copy constructor instead of move constructor? Is `b` in `f()` not a rvalue?

Comment: If you create a [mcve] and build and run it, what is the output you get? What is the output you expect? Why did you expect the expected output?

Comment: Preferential treatment of the copy because the move  isn't marked `nothrow`?

Comment: What do you think would happen if that `return f;` was a `return b;`? Do you think that's not allowed? (Do you think a parameter can only be used once?!)  If it is allowed, how could it work if the move constructor was called already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the expression `b` in the body of `f` is an lvalue. The name of a variable is always an lvalue, even if the variable's declaration has rvalue reference type.

This rule exists because otherwise it would be a little too easy to accidentally move from a variable before you want:

```
void validate(A obj);

void f(A&& b) {
    A a1 = b;
    // Maybe some other code in between.
    A a2 = b;
}
```

Even though some `A` rvalue expression was passed to `f`, once inside `f` it has a name, so the object can be used more than once. If we copy instead of move both times, at least that's safer than moving then trying to use the moved-from variable.

So use `std::move` on an rvalue reference variable name when you know it's the last time you need the variable's value, to explicitly tell that context it's okay to move.